# Не работает метод

Tags: c++, dll, библиотеки

Создаю один проект с консольным приложением, второй - библиотека dll.

Почему на консоль выводится `func2 == 0`? я же, вроде, забиваю туда функцию из библиотеки:

```
// My Project.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
typedef int (* FUNCTION)(int );
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    FUNCTION func2;

    HINSTANCE h;
    if ((h = LoadLibrary(TEXT("New Project1.dll"))) == false)
    {
        cout<<"Dynamic library hasn't been loaded"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (h!= 0)
        {
            func2 = (FUNCTION)GetProcAddress(h, "func2");
            if (func2!=0)
            {
                a = (* func2)(b);
                cout<<a<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"func2 == 0"<<endl;
            }
        }
        else cout<<"h == null"<<endl;
    }
    system("pause");

}
```

вот код библиотек

```
// MyDynamicLib.h
__declspec(dllexport) int func2(int a);


//MyDynamicLib.cpp

#include "MyDynamicLib.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int func2 (int a)
{
    cout<<"func2 from MyDynamicLib with parametr "<<a<<endl;
    return a*2;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте так - typedef int (WINAPI * FUNCTION)(int);

Comment: @Павел Что-то вроде такого  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int func2(int a);?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int func2(int a);
```

Answer (score -1):

Смотрите что возвращает `GetLastError()`.
И как минимум, далеко не всегда `NULL == false && NULL == 0`.